# Implement Dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, implementation, hashcode

I was asked in an interview to implement the dictionary.How to implement it?I have tried implementing it using index as key using array.But Was unable to implement generic dictionary.

Comment: Source code: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs

Comment: I would have refused as it is always better to use the system's implementation ('Always use the System Sort').

Comment: By design, each dictionary members have a key that refers to itself. Differs to array members which based on its position order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to implement a class like `Dictionary<T1, T2>`.
I will describe a simple one.

1. Create a class and a List that stores all contents.
   [Edit] We will compare variables T1 values so a restriction, `where T1 : IEquatable<T1>` is required.

```
class MyDictionary<T1, T2> where T1 : IEquatable<T1>
{
    private List<(T1 key, T2 val)> m_internal_data;
}
```

2. Implement a function that find a value inside the class.
   [Edit] Use `Equals` function. Using `==` causes an error.

```
public T2 Find(T1 key)
{
    // Looking for a content.
    foreach (var content in m_internal_data)
    {
        if (content.key.Equals(key))
        {
            return content.val;
        }
    }
    // It reaches here when there is no content which has the same key.
    // Then, I recommend to throw an exception or return a default value of T2.
    return default(T2);
}
```

3. Implement a function that assign a value.
   [Edit] Use `Equals` too.

```
public void Store(T1 key, T2 val)
{
    // Looking for a content. If exists, store a new value.
    for (int i = 0; i < m_internal_data.Count; i++)
    {
        if (m_internal_data[i].key.Equals(key))
        {
            var content = m_internal_data[i];
            content.val = val;
            m_internal_data[i] = content;
            return;
        }
    }
    // Create a new key.
    m_internal_data.Add((key, val));
}
```

4. Make it able to access a value by using square brackets. Just call previous functions.

```
public T2 this[T1 key]
{
    get => Find(key);
    set
    {
        Store(key, value);
    }
}
```

That's it.

Of course, this is not highly-optimized and has few useful functions. If you want to know how to write Dictionary more useful, I recommend you to read 
[GitHub dotnet/runtime Dictionary.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs), which is included in .NET Core.

Comment: This code would not compile, there are several bugs. It would be nice if you could fix it.

Comment: Thanks! I have fixed all compiler errors. I have reconfirmed that writing code without an editor lets me making bugs.

Comment: This doesn't implement hash table at all, so the lookup time is O(N), contrary to System.Dictionary's (almost) O(1)